# Why is my Java 17 Spring Boot app not reaching my ConfigServer through EurekaServer?

Tags: netflix-eureka, maven-archetype, spring-cloud-config-server

`Hi everyone,

I have an application, Java 17, spring boot 2.6.6.
To register this application and all other we decide to use EurekaServer.
To have differente configuration file, one for each environment, we decided to build a ConfigServer.
So basically what I'm trying to do is go through the eurekaServer to call the ConfigServer and get the required configuration.
If i call the configServer directly from the uri, i can see that it connect correctly to the ConfigRepository in my repo.
The problem is that if i run my app, it doesn't reach the configServer; What it thought is that there is a problem with the EurekaServer.

Below i leave you the application.yml of the 3.

My app:

spring:
security:
oauth2:
resourceserver:
multitenant:
enabled: true
resolve-mode: jwt
jwt:
authorities-converter: io.quantics.multitenant.oauth2.config.KeycloakRealmAuthoritiesConverter
application:
name: springarchetype
cloud:
config:
profile: local
config:
import: "configserver:http://${HOSTNAME_CONFIG_SERVER:eureka}:${PORT_CONFIG_SERVER:8761}/configserver"
boot:
admin:
client:
url: ${ADMIN_SERVER_URL:http://localhost:8761/eureka/adminserver}
profiles:
active: local
eureka:
client:
service-url:
defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka/}

EurekaServer:
eureka:
instance:
instance-id: EurekaServer
client:
register-with-eureka: false
fetch-registry: false
server:
port: 8761

spring:
application:
name: EurekaServer
cloud:
config:
profile: local
config:
import: "configserver:http://${HOSTNAME_CONFIG_SERVER:configserver}:${PORT_CONFIG_SERVER:8888}/"

ConfigServer:

server:
port: 8888

spring:
cloud:
config:
discovery:
enabled: true
service-id: CONFIGSERVER
server:
git:
uri: https://github.com/aprezinterzen/ConfigRepository
username: aprezinterzen
password: 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
clone-on-start: true
application:
name: configserver

eureka:
client:
service-url:
defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka/}

I tried to change in differents way the configurations, but nothing.
Another info, is that EurekaServer reach ConfigServer to take his own configuration.
`